# dataframe merge un-crossed blocks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge some un-crossed blocks. For example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df_11 = pd.DataFrame([[1,1], [1,1]], index=['1', '2'], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df_12 = pd.DataFrame([[2,2], [2,2]], index=['1', '2'], columns=['col3', 'col4'])
df_21 = pd.DataFrame([[3,3], [3,3]], index=['3', '4'], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df_22 = pd.DataFrame([[4,4], [4,4]], index=['3', '4'], columns=['col3', 'col4'])
```

the expected result is

```
   'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'

'1' 1,1,2,2

'2' 1,1,2,2

'3' 3,3,4,4

'4' 3,3,4,4
```

I tried to use `join`:

```
for ele in [df_11, df_12, df_21, df_22]:
    df = df.join(ele, how='outer')
```

But it creates the `Nan` elements which will overlap with the later blocks ( lsuffix and rsuffix).

A naive way is just collecting all columns and index and setting to `df`, which seems not a good way.

Comment: Do you know in advance that df_11/df_21 are on "top" of each other and next to the other two? Or are you looking for a fully programmatic solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know how to arrange the DataFrames, use several [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
out = pd.concat([pd.concat([df_11, df_21]),
                 pd.concat([df_12, df_22])], axis=1)
```

If you want a programmatic approach, you can use a dictionary to group the dataframes per common columns, `concat` those vertically, and `concat` all outputs horizontally:

```
dfs = [df_11, df_12, df_21, df_22]

d = {}
for df in dfs:
    d.setdefault(tuple(df), []).append(df)

out = pd.concat([pd.concat(l) for l in d.values()], axis=1)
```

Or [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) all, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
dfs = [df_11, df_12, df_21, df_22]

out = pd.concat([df.stack() for df in dfs]).unstack()
```

*Note that there should be no overlap.*

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
1     1     1     2     2
2     1     1     2     2
3     3     3     4     4
4     3     3     4     4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `defaultdict` to generate a new dataframe, you do have to test it though for performance, since the solution below essentially morphs the data into a list:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
dfs = [df_11,df_12,df_21,df_22]
container = defaultdict(list)
for df in dfs:
    for name, value in df.items():
        container[name].extend(value)

print(container)
defaultdict(list,
            {'col1': [1, 1, 3, 3],
             'col2': [1, 1, 3, 3],
             'col3': [2, 2, 4, 4],
             'col4': [2, 2, 4, 4]}

pd.DataFrame(container)
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     1     1     2     2
1     1     1     2     2
2     3     3     4     4
3     3     3     4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this solves your problem :)?

```
import pandas as pd

df_11 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1], [1, 1]], index=['1', '2'], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df_12 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2], [2, 2]], index=['1', '2'], columns=['col3', 'col4'])
df_21 = pd.DataFrame([[3, 3], [3, 3]], index=['3', '4'], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df_22 = pd.DataFrame([[4, 4], [4, 4]], index=['3', '4'], columns=['col3', 'col4'])

dfs = [df_11, df_12, df_21, df_22]

# Merge dataframes along the columns axis (axis=1)
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)

# Sort the columns for better readability (optional)
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Comment: code does not work